# Check when Task.Factory.StartNew is done?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm currently stuck on multi threading with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. What I tried to do is to load data async from an API site and then use the data right after.

I tried to do:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(loadSummoner).ContinueWith(init);

private async void loadSummoner() {
    summoner = await riotApi.GetSummonerAsync(region, summonerName);
    leagues = await summoner.GetLeaguesAsync();
}

private void init(Task task) {
    lblSummonerName.Content = summoner.Name;
}
```

But this is not working, since it's just a call train and not a continue from when the first call is completed. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't `Task.Run` your code.

Comment: Oops I meant Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: If your waiting for the task to complete, you should ask yourself, what's the point in threading this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LoadSummoner` method should return `Task`:

```
private async Task LoadSummonerAndLeaguesAsync() {
    summoner = await riotApi.GetSummonerAsync(region, summonerName);
    leagues = await summoner.GetLeaguesAsync();
}
```

Then you just call it like this:

```
LoadSummonerAndLeaguesAsync().ContinueWith(init);
```

Comment: Ahh I see! It's working now! Also, what's the best way to change form controls cross thread? I've done this so far with ObjectDelegate but I'm wondering if there's a better way..

Comment: It should be called using `await`, not `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @TimondeGroot: no threads will be involved in this case. Continuations (whether created via `await` or `ContinueWith`) should be executed in the same context by default, i.e. the application's message loop. You can verify this by setting a breakpoint in the `init` method and inspecting the stack trace, it should show that you are on the main thread.